# Tool to replace the Opera Dragonfly Screenshot Utility

Tags: browser, web-inspector, devtools, web-developer-toolbar, opera-dragonfly

In Opera Dragonfly (the Dev tools used in Opera Presto), there is a tab called Utilities.

In that tab, you can "take a screenshot" which loads an image screenshot of the current page into the dev tools.

You can then zoom in/out and use the color picker and the ruler (with sizes being scaled appropriately to the zoom).

This is very useful when cutting markup as it makes it easy to measure spacing, elements, etc... accurately by zooming in.

I'm looking for a similar extension / tool / addon for Chrome / Opera / Firefox that allows me to measure using a ruler when zoomed in but haven't found anything.

Does anyone know of anything that may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found PixelZoomer for Firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pixelzoomer/) which fulfills this need.

It allow to zoom into a screenshot made, measure pixels and pick colors.